# LG G2 model VS980 4G Bluetooth File Transfer

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer, windows, lg

I am unable to get my LG G2 (Verizon, model VS980 4G) with Android 4.2.2 to successfully transfer files using Bluetooth. I had one app work a few times, then that too stopped working. I can get the phone and computer to pair, but not transfer. Any ideas, this should be simple?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusaists! Just wondering: Could you use an alternative method like USB or WiFi? Bluetooth file transfer has always been quite finicky for me, and it's *very* slow.

Comment: I've now tried standard Windows utility to add wi-fi device which will not connect, and also the Wireless Storage utility on the phone which will only connect after a fresh reboot of the Windows system, and then shows an error after it accepts the password provided by the phone. I have tried this with the firewall up and with it down; same results. Good suggestion though. In attempting bluetooth I get the following specific error if the device will pair and try to load drivers: "Bluetooth peripheral device driver" as it did not load properly. I can find no updated driver at Microsoft or LG.

Comment: Sorry, I worded my question poorly; is there any reason why you can't just use USB? Or are you forced to use the Wireless Storage utility?

Comment: Thanks for your continued interest. I can use USB but it seems like I have a ton of wire entangling my desk already. I was really hoping it would be more efficient to use some wireless technology. I've looked to LG and Microsoft for the bluetooth FTP drivers. LG sent me USB drivers and MS isn't in the loop. I am concluding Bluetooth is only for phone add on devices like headphones and audio. I suspect I'll either need to find an app specifically for this, or use a cloud service if I continue the quest to avoid the wire.

Comment: You've drawn the same conclusions I would have - a cloud service is an idea, or a wifi file-transfer app if the cloud doesn't work well for you. ([There are dozens of these apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=wifi%20file%20transfer&c=apps&hl=en)). Bluetooth file transfers are unfortunately very impractical.